# Using react-native-router, redirecting to different pages not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-router

I have the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from "react-native";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from './components/Home';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <View>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/">
          <Home/>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
      </View>
    </Router>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Whenever I go to `localhost:3000/` or `localhost:3000/home`, a blank page appears which means my components are not being rendered when on these pages. I followed both examples on https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start (web version and native version), however neither seems to work although I think that documentation is slightly outdated because `Switch` was changed to `Routes`.

I can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `react-router-dom` v6, the API changed a bit. Render the routed components on the `Route` component's `element` prop ***as JSX***.

[<Routes> and <Route>](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route)

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <View>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
        </Routes>
      </View>
    </Router>
  );
}
```